# How to remove specific element from array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array

```
Array
(
    [tags] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello
        )

    [assignee] => 60b6a8a38cf91900695dd46b
    [multiple_assignee] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [accountId] => 60b6a8a38cf91900695dd46b
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [accountId] => 5b39d23d32e26a2de15f174f
                )

        )

)
```

I want to remove `60b6a8a38cf91900695dd46b` from the multiple_assignee array.
I have tried with the following code:

```
if (($key = array_search($this->getUsersHashMapValue($responsiblePartyIds[0]), $mutipleAssignee)) !== false) {
                        unset($mutipleAssignee[$key]['accountId']);
                    }
```

But it is not removing that element. The intention is I don't want to repeat the `60b6a8a38cf91900695dd46b` assignee in the multiple assignee array.

I have also tried with the following code:

```
foreach($mutipleAssignee as $subKey => $subArray){
                        if($subArray['accountId'] == $this->getUsersHashMapValue($responsiblePartyIds[0])){
                            unset($mutipleAssignee[$subKey]);
                        }
                    }
```

But it is resulting as

```
Array
(
    [tags] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello
        )

    [assignee] => 60b6a8a38cf91900695dd46b
    [multiple_assignee] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [accountId] => 5b39d23d32e26a2de15f174f
                )

        )

)
```

rather than

```
[multiple_assignee] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [accountId] => 5b39d23d32e26a2de15f174f
                    )
    
            )
```

Thank you

Comment: So is `$mutipleAssignee` the array that you show or only the `multiple_assignee` portion?

Comment: yes, as per shown in the structure, I just want to remove [0] => Array
                (
                    [accountId] => 60b6a8a38cf91900695dd46b
                ) from there, as this value exists as [assignee] => 60b6a8a38cf91900695dd46b

Comment: So you want it removed and you want the array reindexed to start at zero?

Comment: yes but don't know why it is starting from [1] rather than [0]

Comment: Do you really care? If you have two keys, `alpha` and `beta`, removing `alpha` doesn't automatically re-key everything, `alpha` is just gone and `beta` is still there. There isn't anything special about the first item by default being `0`, that's just what PHP does in the absence of any additional information. I would encourage you to never used $array[0] syntax and instead look at [`reset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) or other functions to get "the first" item

Comment: yes sir, because of this I am getting error in JIRA API response

Comment: Okay, that helps to know.

Comment: Yeah in JSON you'll get `{"1":"test"}` instead of `["test"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extract the `accountId` column and search that.  Then use that key:

```
$key = array_search($this->getUsersHashMapValue($responsiblePartyIds[0]), 
                    array_column($mutipleAssignee, 'accountId'));
                    
unset($mutipleAssignee[$key]);
```

After your edit it seems you just want to reindex the subarray after `unset`:

```
$mutipleAssignee = array_values($mutipleAssignee);
```

Comment: after removing why it is starting from [1] => Array
            (
                [accountId] => 5b39d23d32e26a2de15f174f
            ) rather than [0] => Array
            (
                [accountId] => 5b39d23d32e26a2de15f174f
            )

Comment: Because you removed `0`, it doesn't reindex, why would it?  I edited...

Comment: it is showing Array
(
    [tags] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello
        )

    [assignee] => 60b6a8a38cf91900695dd46b
    [multiple_assignee] => Array
        (
        )

) as result

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a simple `for` loop. All of the `array_*` functions are really helpful but I find that they hide nuances. Since I don't have your functions I'm just making a plain-old one, but you should be able to port this.

```php
$data = [
    'tags' => [
        'hello',
    ],
    'assignee' => '60b6a8a38cf91900695dd46b',
    'multiple_assignee' => [
        [
            'accountId' => '60b6a8a38cf91900695dd46b',
        ],
        [
            'accountId' => '5b39d23d32e26a2de15f174f',
        ],
    ],
];


$assignee = $data['assignee'];
foreach ($data['multiple_assignee'] as $multiple_assignee_key => $multiple_assignee) {
    // if the root assignee is also listed in the multiple assignee area
    if ($multiple_assignee['accountId'] === $assignee) {
        // remove the duplicate from the multiple area
        unset($data['multiple_assignee'][$multiple_assignee_key]);
        
        // re-index the array
        $data['multiple_assignee'] = array_values($data['multiple_assignee']);
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```php
array(3) {
  ["tags"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "hello"
  }
  ["assignee"]=>
  string(24) "60b6a8a38cf91900695dd46b"
  ["multiple_assignee"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["accountId"]=>
      string(24) "5b39d23d32e26a2de15f174f"
    }
  }
}
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/tYppK